# node shows all taxonomy terms with images (the not matching are greyed)

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I need the node to show all terms of the taxonomy 'months' (not only the matching ones) with only the matching ones in evidence, i.e. not greyed.

I can imagine I can define a couple of image fields for the terms (one coloured, the other one greyed) but can't figure out how to have my node show all of them and choose the coloured image for the matching ones.

many many thanks

Angelo